# Let $K\subseteq F$ be a finite extension of fields, $M$ and $N$ intermediate fields separable on $K$. Show that $MN$ (compositum) is separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K\subseteq F$ be a finite extension of fields, $M$ and $N$ intermediate fields separable on $K$. Show that $MN$ (compositum) is separable.

Using the Element Primitive Theorem, we know that $M=K(a)$ and $M=K(b)$, hence $MN=K(a)K(b)=K(a,b)$ therefore $MN$ is separable since $a$ and $b$ are separable.

My proof is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong if you are allowed to use the primitive element theorem. However, note that the result is true even if the extensions are infinite. Specifically, given any field extension $K / F$ with separable subextensions $M / F$ and $N / F$, $MN / F$ is separable. To prove this, you just take any element in $MN$ and consider how it was generated, which needs only finitely many elements in $M,N$. By adjoining these to $F$ we get a chain of separable extensions which must be separable.